# Can't establish ODBC connection to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, odbc, cdata-drivers

I'm trying to connect to SharePoint using the free "CData" ODBC Driver for Sharepoint. Wehn trying to configure the DSN, I enter the SharePoint site I am using (sharepoint.xx.xxx.com) I then enter the username (user@domain.com) and password that I typically would use to logon to SharePoint online. However it returns the error "401 Unauthorized". Am I using the wrong account in this attempt?

Answer (score 0):

By default, our ODBC Driver for SharePoint is configured to connect to an on-premises instance of SharePoint. Can you set the **SharePoint Edition** connection property to "SharePoint Online"? That should resolve the issue.

If that doesn't resolve the issue, our [Support Team](http://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx) will be happy to help.